# Assigned variable empty outside of switch statement PHP

Tags: php, variables, scope, switch-statement

```
public function store($feed) 
    {
        switch($feed)
        {
            case 'full':
                $coupons = json_decode(file_get_contents('path-to-json-feed'), true);
                break;
            case 'incremental':
                $coupons = json_decode(file_get_contents('path-to-different-json-feed'), true);
                break;
         }
        var_dump($coupons);die();
        $this->Deal_model->updateAllDeals($coupons);
        echo 'Coupons Updated';     
    }
```

I am trying to assign a value to `$coupons` but `var_dump($coupons)` returns an empty array.

Comment: So and your question is?

Comment: If `$feed` is neither "full" nor "incremental", then `$coupons` will be empty... so have you verified the value of `$feed`?

Comment: sorry first post and i screwed it all up. The $coupons variable is returning as an empty array when var_dumped.

Comment: If i var_dump $feed it is a string "incremental"

Comment: @mjamieson What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($feed);` (Take the output from the source code)?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `default`?

Comment: If `$coupons` is an empty array, then validate what you're getting back from 'path-to-json-feed', make sure it actually contains data

Comment: $feed is string(11) "incremental"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you add a `default`, in case `$feed` is something other than `full` or `incremental`.

If this is your actual code, I am not sure if there is a file called `path-to-json-feed`, but it seems like it should be something else, like the actual path to a JSON file/feed.

Replace `path-to-json-feed` with an actual file, and try with the below code and see what you get.

```
public function store($feed) 
{
    switch($feed)
    {
        case 'full':
            $coupons = json_decode(file_get_contents('path-to-json-feed'), true);
            break;
        case 'incremental':
            $coupons = json_decode(file_get_contents('path-to-json-feed'), true);
            break;
        default:
            $coupons = json_decode(file_get_contents('path-to-json-feed'), true);
            break;
     }
    var_dump($coupons);
    die(); // DEBUGGING
    $this->Deal_model->updateAllDeals($coupons);
    echo 'Coupons Updated';     
}
```

Comment: Would it help others to make it clear this code is for debugging purposes only and not a working answer?. I appreciate that the 'die()' statement is a big clue. :)

Comment: You should combine any relevant cases that have duplicated content - DRY